# System gesture gate timed out. Flutter IOS

Tags: ios, flutter, dart

Hi I'm trying to record a video when user presses the `GestureDetector` long enough. Here is the code.

```
GestureDetector(
                                    excludeFromSemantics: true,
                                    behavior: HitTestBehavior.opaque,
                                    onLongPressEnd: (details) async {
                                      final file = File((await controller!
                                              .stopVideoRecording())
                                          .path);

                                      BlocProvider.of<ShareFluParentBloc>(
                                              context)
                                          .add(SelectImageRequested(
                                              imageFile: AssetTypeModel(
                                                  file: file, isVideo: true),
                                              isVideo: true));
                                      var pageBloc =
                                          context.read<PageStackBloc>();
                                      pageBloc.add(
                                          PushPageRequested(page: "setShare"));
                                      context.goNamed("setShare");
                                    },
                                    onLongPressDown: (details) async {
                                      await controller!.startVideoRecording();
                                    },
                                    onTap: () async {
                                      final file = File(
                                          (await controller!.takePicture())
                                              .path);

                                      BlocProvider.of<ShareFluParentBloc>(
                                              context)
                                          .add(SelectImageRequested(
                                              imageFile: AssetTypeModel(
                                                  file: file, isVideo: false),
                                              isVideo: false));

                                      var pageBloc =
                                          context.read<PageStackBloc>();
                                      pageBloc.add(
                                          PushPageRequested(page: "setShare"));
                                      context.goNamed(
                                        "setShare",
                                      );
                                    },
                                    child: Container(
                                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width *
                                          Dimensions.w85,
                                      height:
                                          MediaQuery.of(context).size.width *
                                              Dimensions.w85,
                                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                          border: Border.all(
                                              color: AppColors.primary,
                                              width: 2),
                                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
                                              (MediaQuery.of(context)
                                                          .size
                                                          .width *
                                                      Dimensions.w85) /
                                                  2)),
                                    ))
```

This code works for android devices (Real and Simulators) but it's not working for IOS device.
What am i doing wrong.